# Overriding File class toString without having to create objects in the overriding class type

Tags: java, overriding

I have an `ArrayList` of files that i want to print to the console.. i'm fine with the `toString()` method of the `ArrayList` class but i don't want to print the pathname of the `File` objects i wan't to print their names as when calling `getName()` method.

I want to do it as simple as this:

```
class overridingClass extends File {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Super.getName();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to somehow override File `toString()` method without having to change my `File` objects to be `overridingClass` objects

PS: I have been searching for a couple of hours for this and couldn't even find anything about overriding a built-in class method so if anyone could make a Q&A if they can't find anything about it too would be great and probably put a link here

Comment: No. If you want `overridingClass.toString()` to be called then your objects must be of type `overridingClass` (or subclasses).

Comment: If it is important enough, create a subclass. If it isn't important enough, use something other than `toString()`.

Comment: Why don't you just use `print(file.getName())`?

Comment: thx... i just wanted to know if it is impossible or there is a workaround but it looks like i have to loop throw the arraylist printing every file name manually or change the objects type..
now that this post is done without any answers.. should i delete it or close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to bind the the custom print method directly to the `File` object breaks the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). There might be multiple valid ways to print the contents of a list. Adding every print method directly into the class would quickly bloat the class, and also confuse users of the class.

The most practical way to do this would be to create a separate object or utility method that performs this work.

```
public class FileNamePrinter {
    public String print(List<File> files) {
        StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner("," "[", "]");
        for (File file : files) {
            joiner.add(file.getName());
        }
        return joiner.toString();
    }
}
```

In you're regular logic you can now use this `FilePrinter` object to perform the translation.

```
List<File> files = ...;
FileNamePrinter printer = new FileNamePrinter();
System.out.println(printer.print(files));
```

Another option would be to transform the file list into a list of strings based on the `getName` method, and then print that list

```
System.out.println(files.stream()
    .map(File::getName)
    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```